# Using Python's logging module to record trace_id

Tags: python, logging, trace

My program imports a library and only uses one function from it called `do_stuff()`. The library has loggers set up the usual way in each of its modules. The main program also has loggers set up the same way.

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

I want to prepend a trace_id to the *library*'s logs only for easier retrieval in the future. All of library logs should have the same ID prepended for each call. For example, it should look something like:

```
[INFO] log in main program
[INFO] [abcdef] first log in library call 1
[INFO] [abcdef] second log in library call 1
[INFO] [abcdef] third log in library call 1
[INFO] back to main
[INFO] [qwerty] first log in library call 2
[INFO] [qwerty] second log in library call 2
[INFO] [qwerty] third log in library call 2
[INFO] program end
```

I looked into `opentelemetry`'s python implementation but it seems unnecessarily complex for my purposes. I also tried using Custom logger class but [can't seem to get it to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77816989/python-logging-global-variable-in-an-imported-library).

Answer (score 0):

## Easy Solution: Use the logger's name as trace_id

This is the easiest: When you call `getLogger`, you pass in the name for that logger. We can use that name instead of `trace_id`. Here is the project's structure:

```
├── lib1.py
├── lib2.py
└── main.py
```

```py
# main.py
import logging

import lib1
import lib2

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format="[%(levelname)s] [%(name)s] %(message)s",
)
logger = logging.getLogger("main")


def main():
    """Entry"""
    logger.info("log in main program")
    lib1.do_stuff()
    logger.info("back to main")
    lib2.do_stuff()
    logger.info("program end")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```py
# lib1.py
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger("abcdef")


def do_stuff():
    logger.info("first log in library call 1")
    logger.info("second log in library call 1")
    logger.info("third log in library call 1")
```

```py
# lib2.py
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger("qwerty")


def do_stuff():
    logger.info("first log in library call 2")
    logger.info("second log in library call 2")
    logger.info("third log in library call 2")
```

Output:

```
[INFO] [main] log in main program
[INFO] [abcdef] first log in library call 1
[INFO] [abcdef] second log in library call 1
[INFO] [abcdef] third log in library call 1
[INFO] [main] back to main
[INFO] [qwerty] first log in library call 2
[INFO] [qwerty] second log in library call 2
[INFO] [qwerty] third log in library call 2
[INFO] [main] program end
```

I like this solution because it is simple and we don't have to do any thing extra to get the functionality we want. If for some reason, this does not work out, I would like to offer another solution, which involves `logging.LoggerAdapter`

## Solution: Use logging.LoggerAdapter

Reference: [LoggerAdapter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.LoggerAdapter)

In this solution, I will create a logger adapter `MyLogger`, which will take in an existing logger object and a `trace_id` and return a new logger object.

In this solution, the project looks like this:

```
├── lib1.py
├── lib2.py
├── main.py
└── mylogger.py
```

Notice the addition of the mylogger.py module.

```py
# main.py
import logging

import lib1
import lib2

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format="[%(levelname)s] %(message)s",
)


def main():
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.info("log in main program")
    lib1.do_stuff()
    logger.info("back to main")
    lib2.do_stuff()
    logger.info("program end")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```py
# mylogger.py
import logging


# doc: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.LoggerAdapter
class MyLogger(logging.LoggerAdapter):
    def process(self, msg, kwargs):
        trace_id = self.extra.get("trace_id")
        if trace_id:
            msg = f"[{trace_id}] {msg}"
        return msg, kwargs

    @classmethod
    def new(cls, trace_id):
        """Create a new logger with trace_id."""
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        new_logger = cls(logger, {"trace_id": trace_id})
        return new_logger
```

```py
# lib1.py
from mylogger import MyLogger

logger = MyLogger.new("abcdef")


def do_stuff():
    """This is in library 1"""
    logger.info("first log in library call 1")
    logger.info("second log in library call 1")
    logger.info("third log in library call 1")
```

```py
# lib2.py
from mylogger import MyLogger

logger = MyLogger.new("qwerty")


def do_stuff():
    """This is in library 2"""
    logger.info("first log in library call 2")
    logger.info("second log in library call 2")
    logger.info("third log in library call 2")
```

Output:

```
[INFO] log in main program
[INFO] [abcdef] first log in library call 1
[INFO] [abcdef] second log in library call 1
[INFO] [abcdef] third log in library call 1
[INFO] back to main
[INFO] [qwerty] first log in library call 2
[INFO] [qwerty] second log in library call 2
[INFO] [qwerty] third log in library call 2
[INFO] program end
```

This solution creates a class `MyLogger`, which adds the `trace_id` to the log output. Note that `MyLogger` is initialized with 2 parameters: (1) An existing logger object, and (2) A dictionary. This dictionary will becomes the `self.extra` in method `process()`. See the documentation for details. For the sake of simplicity, I created a class function `new` to make it simpler for the caller.

The method `process` takes a message, plus kwargs and modify that message with the `trace_id` and return--that are all it need, the rest will be handled by the `logging` framework.

This solution is more complex than the first. That is why I like the first one better.

Comment: Hai, thanks for your answer but as mentioned in my question, I only use one function in the library. I'd like a unique trace to each call to the *same* function (aka same module). Your solution only works if I call different modules from the library.

Comment: So basically, you want to know who calls this function. Correct?